# How to pass form values from jquery ajax to codeigniter controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to create a contact form that send email. I am using jquery ajax. 
My question is how can I pass the form values from jquery ajax to codeigniter function?
This is my html form:

```
<form id="ph-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" id="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" id="email"  />
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject*" id="subject"  />
    <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Messaage*" id="message" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Send Message" id="submit_btn">
</form>
```

This is my jquery ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(){
        var form_data = {
            name : $('#name').val(),
            email : $('#email').val(),
            subject : $('#subject').val(),
            message : $('#message').val(),
            ajax : '1'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '<?= $this->config->site_url().$this->uri->uri_string() ?>',
            async : false,
            data : form_data,
            success : function(data){
                alert("wew success!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

And finally my controller:

```
public function test($view){
    switch($view){
        case 'contact1':
            $this->load->view('ph-contact1');
            break;
        case 'contact2':
            $this->load->view('ph-contact2');
            break;
        case 'contact3':
            $this->load->view('ph-contact3');
            break;
                default:
                    $this->load->view('ph-contact1');
                    break;
    }

    if($this->input->post('ajax') == '1'){
        echo "<script>alert(".$this->input->post('name').")</script>";
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the ajax is working and I don't have form validation.

Answer (score 0):

First change input "submit" to "button" to prevent page refresh.

```
<input type="button" name="send_message" value="Send Message" id="submit_btn">
```

then url will be

```
url : "<?= site_url().'your_controller_name/test'; ?>",
```

this will be post data on your controller function test, then you get post data by `$this->input->post('ajax')`. for debugging you can use console by inspect element of browser

Comment: Thank you for your response. sorry I missed something on the controller. I use url : '<?= $this->config->site_url().$this->uri->uri_string() ?>' to get the exact url. I am using switch case so the url will become localhost/sample/test/ph-contact1. I just want to know how can I passed the form value from ajax then pass it to the controller

Comment: i think your code is ok you need just post url `localhost/sample/test/`

Comment: ph-contact1 also pass through post or 'localhost/sample/test/ph-contact1'

Comment: you can debug ajax through console

Comment: Thanks again. I already debug it using the console and i think it's working fine cuz there are no errors. How can I catch the value of ajax to the controller?

Comment: $this->input->post('ajax'), $this->input->post('name') or $_POST['name']

Comment: wow! is that the code? I'm so stupid, I didn't think about that. How can I debug if the value was catch by the controller?

Comment: just echo your values then all echo will be show in console

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok to pass values to your controller by ajax

You can get your form values separately like

```
$this->input->post('name');
$this->input->post('email');
$this->input->post('subject');
$this->input->post('message');
```

Also please confirm once that your requested url is pointing to given controller or not from console of your browse.

Hope this will help you. Let me know if still you are facing any problem.